# Gluster puppet mount not working

Tags: linux, puppet, puppet-enterprise, glusterfs

I am trying to mount a gluster volume called storage-test on my webserver with the manifest syntax below:

```
gluster::mount { '/glusterfs':
   ensure    => present,
   volume    => "storage:/storage-test",
   options   => 'defaults',
   transport => 'tcp',
   atboot    => true,
   dump      => 0,
   pass      => 0,
}
```

When I run `puppet agent -t` everything is processed fine with no issues. I then check `/etc/fstab` and I see this entry: `storage:/storage-test    /glusterfs  glusterfs       defaults,transport=tcp  0       0` but when I type `mount` I don't see any entry regarding the mount as defined above there and when I also type `df -h`, I don't see any entry there as well. After I check all of this, I reboot the webserver. After the webserver comes back up, when I type `mount` I do see the mount point and the same applies to when I type `df -h`, I see the mount entry there as well. After about a minute, when I perform the same checks, the mount entry that was showing after the reboot is no longer in `mount` or `df -h`.

I have also tried setting `ensure => mounted` but when I run puppet, it says the status has changed from unmounted to mounted and then it just hangs to the point where I have to reboot the server to recover and even with that, when I type `df -h` it hangs again. What I'm I doing wrong? why isnt't the volume mounting? Any help would be greatly appreciated to resolve this.

I am running glusterfs 3.12.3 for both server and client. Module version is the latest version

Comment: Something is not right with your mount. It should be fine with `ensure => mounted`.  Just try to mount it manually and check logs on the server.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was spelling the volume name wrong